# XML XSD Valid fail

Tags: xml, xsd

i put xml and xsd in the free location. http://xixishuile1.kilu.de/
and use the http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html to validate the xml, it give me response CATALOG fail.
who could help me.

Comment: Please provide more details... it's hard to see what's your actual problem!

Comment: I just start to know XML and XSD.

Comment: I just start to know XML and XSD. I know xml contain contents, and xsd contain structure. my example is popular internet example. xml describe CD storage. <CATALOG> is root element. it content several same structured sub-element "<CD>". the internet give me the example xsd which describe how to define <CD>, but not tell me how to descri be <CATALOG>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, welcome to SO. Since you're learning XML/XSD, I would recommend you download and use some specialized XML/XSD editors. All that I know offer free evaluations, so it should be easy to get started.

Such a tool would help you generate an XSD based on your XML, which should get you started in understanding what might be needed to get your problem fixed: comparing the XSD you've posted with the one you have is a good learning approach, as it tells you what pieces you missed and eventually narrow your search re: what to learn first.

So here is an XSD I've generated from your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="CATALOG">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CD">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="TITLE" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="ARTIST" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="COUNTRY" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="COMPANY" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="PRICE" type="xsd:decimal" />
              <xsd:element name="YEAR" type="xsd:unsignedShort" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

At a glance:

- your XSD has a targetNamespace, and the generated one doesn't; to fix it, you either remove the targetNamespace in your XSD, or add a default namespace to your root XML like so:

  <CATALOG xmlns="http://www.xixishuile1.kilu.de/">
- the CATALOG element is now defined for you. It is similar to the CD (it is complex, content model is sequenced); since you want multiple CD elements, there's a maxOccurs attribute (particle occurrence attribute) showing `unbounded`.

So the above tells you that so far you need to read on how to, or not, target namespaces in your XSD, and how to define complex content models.

Also, have a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help on asking a good question...

Comment: thanks for giving me so clear helpful answer. i could clearly understand how to define CATALOG, but i still could not understand targetNamespace keyword. is there any helpful picture or description to explain it?

Comment: You should read about XML namespaces... a schema targetNamespace places content in a particular XML namespace.